# How to add a click method in sensor

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, sensors

I have successfully, with a fellow programmers help to create the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SensorTestActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private boolean color = false;
    private View view;
    private long lastUpdate;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        view = findViewById(R.id.label);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            getAccelerometer(event);
        }

    }

    private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
        float[] values = event.values;
        // Movement
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];

        float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
                / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
        {
            if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
                return;
            }
            lastUpdate = actualTime;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device has shaken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            if (color) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            color = !color;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register this class as a listener for the orientation and
        // accelerometer sensors
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // unregister listener
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Right now i am trying to add something like..

```
Switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
      public void onClick(View v) { 
          if (sensorIsOn) { 
              //deactivate it 
           } else { 
              //activate it 
          } 
    } 

});
```

I want to click on a button and deseable sensor and on clicking again enabling it!

Comment: Trying to add the button

Answer (score 0):

You should just register or unregister the listener. Just as you should in onPause and onResume (I think).

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, jAccelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
```

Comment: I don't know if you can do more than that as you're implementing SensorEventListener with your class definition.

Comment: If you want to know how to add a Button, go to the API demos. I hope that's not really what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

in `onCreate()` method , after you register the sensor's listener, set the Tag of your `Switch` button to true :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        view = findViewById(R.id.label);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Button Switch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch_button);
        Switch.setTag(true);
        //set the listener for your Switch button here
    }
```

And in the `onClick()` method : try this code  :

```
Switch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
      public void onClick(View v) { 
          boolean isSensorActivated = (boolean) v.getTag();
          if(isSensorActivated) {
              mSensorManager.registerListener(this, jAccelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
          }
          else {
              mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
          }
          v.setTag(!isSensorActivated);
     } 

});
```

Comment: I have some problems with your method, first of all it says unregister is not applicable for newsetonclick listener..secondly about boolean, it can't cast object to boolean and lastly it does not accepts jaccelometer as variable

Comment: you aren't supposed to use the jAccel var bud

Comment: Use exactly what you use in onPause and onResume. Then you're good

Comment: sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 
sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

Comment: You can probably call a method from onClickListener() or set a static field to hold your Sensor.

Comment: change `this` with `YourActivityName.this` , and  about the boolean is just an alternative, you can use an integer instead of boolean as a Tag of your Button and all is done :)